# Issue an access token for an IdentityServer4 instance

Tags: identityserver4

Inside an application that is running IdentityServer4, I want to get an access token so that that the app can access another service that requires authentication. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768088/how-can-i-issue-an-access-token-to-the-identityserver-itself) that addresses IdentityServer3. I want to know if there is a similar mechanism in IdentityServer4.

I've already tried searching the github repo for `IssueClientToken` but got no hits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was pointed out to me in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41510313/7214480), you can inject `IdentityServerTools` into your class and use the exposed methods to create access tokens for Identity Server extensibility points. For instance a short lived token for a resource api might look like this:

```
     // generate short lived token
     var accessToken = await _identityServerTools.IssueJwtAsync(500, 
         new Claim[] { new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Audience, "resourceApi") });
```